# Check-Box is not checked through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

---

I was working on a project in that some situation comes out that:

- optionC is by default checked When someone checked optionA and
  optionB then optionC should unchecked When someone checked optionC
  after it unchecked then optionB should unchecked When someone check

ed optionB after it unchecked then optionA should unchecked--- Thats All!
Here is my Code:

```js
var optionA = document.getElementById("optionA");
var optionB = document.getElementById("optionB");
var optionC = document.getElementById("optionC");
optionC.checked = true;
[ optionA, optionB, optionC ].forEach(function(option) {
   option.addEventListener("click", function() {
      if(optionA.checked && optionB.checked){
        optionC.checked = false;
      }
     else if(optionA.checked && optionB.checked && optionC.checked){
       optionB.checked = false;
     }
       //Here also Code is missing
     else{
  optionC.checked = true;
     }
   });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="optionA" name="optionA" />
  <label for="optionA">Option A</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="optionB" name="optionB" />
  <label for="optionB">Option B</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="optionC" name="optionC" />
  <label for="optionC">Option C</label>
</div>
```

**But I am facing an Error** That after optionC is unchecked user is not able to check it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify objective:

- `#optionC` is `checked` by default
- If both `#optionA` and `#optionB`<sup>✥</sup> are checked by the user, `#optionC` is unchecked
- If `#optionB` is checked by the user, `#optionA` is unchecked
- If `#optionC` is checked by the user, `#optionB` is unchecked

<sup><sup>✥</sup>`#optionB` must be checked before `#optionA` is checked</sup>

**Details are commented in example**

```js
// Reference <form>
const abc = document.forms.ABC;
// Bind "change" event to <form>
abc.onchange = options;

/**
 * Event handler passes the Event object by default
 * io - Reference all <input>
 * chk - Reference the element the user un/checked
 * A, B, C - Each <input>
 * If the element the user un/checked has [name="option"]...
 * and if the <input> the user un/checked is #optionA AND
 * it's checked AND #optionB is checked...
 * uncheck #optionC then end function
 * and if the <input> the user un/checked is #optionB AND 
 * it's checked AND #optionA is checked...
 * uncheck #optionA then end function
 * and if the <input> the user un/checked is #optionC AND 
 * it's checked AND #optionB is checked...
 * uncheck #optionB then end function
 */
function options(event) {
  const io = this.elements;
  const chk = event.target;
  const A = io.optionA;
  const B = io.optionB;
  const C = io.optionC;

  if (chk.name === "option") {
    if (chk === A && A.checked && B.checked) {
      return C.checked = false;
    }
    if (chk === B && B.checked && A.checked) {
      return A.checked = false;
    }
    if (chk === C && C.checked && B.checked) {
      return B.checked = false;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="ABC">
  <input id="optionA" name="option" type="checkbox">
  <label for="optionA">Option A</label>
  <input id="optionB" name="option" type="checkbox">
  <label for="optionB">Option B</label>
  <!--
    Add the checked attribute to #optionC to start it as checked by default
  -->
  <input id="optionC" name="option" type="checkbox" checked>
  <label for="optionC">Option C</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks you for guiding me in detail but is there is a way to check optionA first?

Comment: You're very welcome. Sure, as in the second rule wherein A and B closes C? You'll need to change what B closes or change it so B closes nothing and A closes C or B. You'll need to give me the details of the changes, as you can imagine there are several possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Your code was wrong because you should also refer to the data of who the `checkbox` fired the click event, I fixed the code by using [`e.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) to check who fired the event

```js
var optionA = document.getElementById("optionA");
var optionB = document.getElementById("optionB");
var optionC = document.getElementById("optionC");
optionC.checked = true;
[ optionA, optionB, optionC ].forEach(function(option) {
   option.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      const elem = e.target;
      if(elem == optionB) {
          if(optionC.checked)
            optionA.checked = false;
      }
      if(elem == optionA) {
          if(optionB.checked)
            optionC.checked = false;
      }
      if(elem == optionC) {
          if(optionA.checked)
            optionB.checked = false;
      }
   });
});
```

```html
<div>
     A
     <input type="checkbox" id="optionA" />
</div>
<div>
     B
     <input type="checkbox" id="optionB" />
</div>
<div>
    C
    <input type="checkbox" id="optionC" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, you for guiding but still it doesn't meet to my requirement that when user select optionA then OptionB then the OptionA is unchecked instead of OptionC. Do you have any solution. I am trying for a couple of days but I can't. Once again Thanks